# Java: convert birth data to days

Tags: java, days

I really need some help with the specific assignment. The user inputs birth data (YYYY MM DD) and the program tells you how old you are in days :

The outprint in console would be

You are for example born 1981 11 06

You are 7068 days old.

I've rewritten my code maybe 20 times without success, and any help would be so much appreciated, i'm kinda new so everything will be helpful! thanks a lot in advance,
Sebastian.

// the code ... :) EDITED .. I RE-WROTED THE CODE, since it didnt work anyhow i twisted and turned it so i changed it completly, but can someone tell me why DateFormat and Date date is not working Eclipse is also giving me error on ParseException..

Its working perfectly now ! thanks for all support!

Comment: You should add the homework tag, if it is an assignment.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried and explain how it failed to do what you wanted it to.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the [Calendar class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)? It has functions for parsing dates from strings and comparing them.

Comment: If this is a class assignment I doubt that is permitted.

Comment: @Aidanc - it could be ... for an assignment in an introductory programming course.

Comment: @Aidanc, unless there are specifically listed constraints, then it's fair game IMO. Is the Date class also excluded? If so, how do you know the current date? Is the String class excluded? etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [DateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) class which you can utilize the .parse() on the input.  Which gives you a [Date](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class which then has .getTime() which returns the number of milliseconds.  Then create a new Date class and subtract the .getTime() milliseconds.  Convert to Days.

```
Date birth = DateFormat.parse(inputString);
Date now = new Date();
long diff = now.getTime() - now.getTime();
int days = ((((diff / 1000) / 60) / 60) / 24)
```

EDIT:
According to the code you listed below, you should just be able to do

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print ("Enter birth date (yyyy/mm/dd): ");
String yourBirthDay=input.nextLine();
Date birth = DateFormat.parse(yourBirthDay);
Date now = new Date();
long diff = now.getTime() - now.getTime();
int days = ((((diff / 1000) / 60) / 60) / 24)
```

Comment: It is just a introduction programming course I have been studying java for around 1 and a half weeks right now, and Im stuck here.

Comment: The teacher advices us with gregorian calender but any calender will go well, but can it calculate the leap years aswell ( every 4 years february has 29 days )

Comment: @Sebastian: a) sorry for misspelling your name above, b) the Date class does take into account the leap year.

Comment: Alright but the code I have written is kind of big and im not sure how to implement this new calender you guys introduced to me, anyone think they could see my code and help me figure it out?

Comment: Thanks Suroot for the answer, really appreciated :)

Comment: I have edited in the code at the top :) thanks for all of you who answered really helping-a-want-to-learn-new-to-the-java-thing guy :)

Comment: is there a way of changing to the calender you guys adviced without messing up so much in the code? Im now in the state of a questionmark and im clueless!

Comment: It is still not run-compatible and its not working :( I cant figure out whats wrong with the code, please could anyone try run this program, I dont even know what to do should I start over? /Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Well, when I imported the needed class, it worked just fine:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
```

The error Eclipse gave you is probably because you didn't import the correct classes.

A little hint: use `ctrl + shift + o` to add missing imports in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

In Java 8 and later, you could use the java.time classes such as [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) and [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). Perhaps not appropriate to a homework assignment though.

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( LocalDate.parse( "1981-11-06" ) , LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ) ;
```